Generalization of the Birkhoff Factorization
Background
Let $\Delta:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}, b\Delta:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$ and consider a Hölder continuous matrix function on the boundary $G\in \mathcal{C}^{k,\alpha}(b\Delta,GL_n(\mathbb{C})).$ Then there is a ''smooth diagonalization'', the Birkhoff factorization
$$-\overline{G(\zeta)}^{-1}G(\zeta)=\Theta(\zeta)\begin{pmatrix}
\zeta^{\kappa_1}&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots & \vdots\\
0&\ldots&\zeta^{\kappa_n}
\end{pmatrix}\overline{\Theta(\zeta)}^{-1}\quad \forall \zeta\in b\Delta,$$
here $\Theta:\overline{\Delta}\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $\mathcal{C}^{k,\alpha}$ continuous and holomorphic on the interior $\Delta$ and the $\kappa_1,\ldots,\kappa_n$ are integers.
My Question
Can this be generalized to higher dimensions?
For example, take the two-dimensional case. Write $\Delta^2:=\Delta\times\Delta, b\Delta^2=b\Delta\times b\Delta$ and take $G\in\mathcal{C}^{k,\alpha}(b\Delta^2,GL_n(\mathbb{C})).$
Can we again find a factorization
$$-\overline{G(\zeta)}^{-1}G(\zeta)=\Theta(\zeta)\begin{pmatrix}
\zeta_1^{\kappa_{1}}\zeta_2^{\lambda_{1}}&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots & \vdots\\
0&\ldots&\zeta_1^{\kappa_{n}}\zeta_2^{\lambda_{n}}
\end{pmatrix}\overline{\Theta(\zeta)}^{-1}\quad \forall \zeta\in b\Delta^2,$$
where $\Theta:\overline{\Delta^2}\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $\mathcal{C}^{k,\alpha}$ continuous and holomorphic on the interior?
If this is not always possible, what are the obstructions? Any references would be appreciated.
